# Not getting a full 3.3V instead getting like 0.7V on a GPIO pin

Tags: gpio, python, power, rpi.gpio

Okay so I ran the following code and I am seeing ~0.70V on the GPIO pin and not 3.3V. Why could that be?

```
#import the GPIO and time package
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18,True)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Actually now i'm getting 0.20V

Comment: keep looping, no clean up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will set the output Low for about 1 microsecond then reconfigure it as an INPUT.

So depending on what is connected this is expected.

If you want the state to persist remove the call to cleanup.